# How to find the Action Override with its Id?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

While deleting my Aura Component via VSCode, I got an error which says : 'Action Override is referencing the component : 04u9D0000004psV.'

It seems an action is override by the AC and its Id is '04u9D0000004psV'. But I cannot find the action anywhere.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use tooling api, you can try this:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query --usetoolingapi --query 
"SELECT MetadataComponentName, MetadataComponentType, 
 RefMetadataComponentName, RefMetadataComponentType 
 FROM MetadataComponentDependency Where MetadataComponentId = '04u9D0000004psV'"
```

Or you can use "Query Editor" in developer console too and use tooling api check to query this:

```
SELECT MetadataComponentName, MetadataComponentType, RefMetadataComponentName, RefMetadataComponentType FROM MetadataComponentDependency Where MetadataComponentId = '04u9D0000004psV'
```

Comment: Thank you, I cannot get any record in current sandbox, does that mean other sanbox under the same production enviornment will also prevent me from deleting the aura component?

Answer (score 0):

Check if any standard button is overridden by the aura component which you are trying to delete.

Remove that component from from below screen.
[image]

It resolved my issue.